# VM Arguments with maven-failsafe-plugin

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, build-automation, maven-plugin

I'm trying to pass a VM argument into Maven, specifically for a suite of tests run by failsafe.

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-Dtest.data=true</argLine>
  </configuration>
  <version>2.7.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>integration-test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>verify</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>verify</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

When I run the command `mvn clean verify` the tests that rely on test.data being set to true are failing. However, when I run the command `mvn -Dtest.data=true clean verify` the tests all pass. I need the argument to be set inside the pom for my CI environment.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance,

Pete

Comment: First recomendation is to update to 2.8 of Maven-FailSafe-Plugin. Are you forking the JVM?

Comment: I've updated to 2.8 and still not working. How do I know if I'm forking the JVM? I don't believe I am.

Comment: The defaults say you are forking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out that the integration tests that I was trying to run needed to have this argument passed into the Tomcat plugin not the Failsafe plugin. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: I see the same issue, but because I'm not using Tomcat I wasn't able to fix it this way. Finnaly I have adjusted my Jenkins job with specifying in the Build section:
    clean test -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true

Answer (score 4):

Use the `<systemPropertyVariables>` element [to set system properties](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) (I don't see where `<argLine>` is mentioned in the documentation, where did you find it?):

```
<configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
        <test.data>true</test.data>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I've tried this as well but still not working. <argLine> is in source code, but I haven't checked the docs.

Comment: Here are the docs for maven-failsafe-plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html